# proof of Cantor-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: set-theory, cantor-set

let $f$, $g$  injective functions

$f:E\rightarrow F$ and $g:F\rightarrow E$

consider this set defined as follow

$\mathcal F=\left\{C\subset E,  g\left(F-f(C)\right)\subseteq E-C\right\}$

i have proved that $\mathcal F$ is non empty

how i can prove that $K \in \mathcal L$ where $K=\bigcup\limits_{C\in \mathcal F}C$

please help me with this question